# Where can I store my application's files?

Tags: objective-c, macos, path, directory

Well, I'm new to the Mac OS X platform and seriously I don't know anything about it. I mean on Windows I just store it at the Program's Files directory, What about the Mac, is there any recommended place to put the files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resources related to your application that *will not be changed* after the app is installed going into the app wrapper (see documentation).

Cached data that can be deleted at any time goes in ~/Library/Caches.

Supporting data that should generally be persisted, but isn't document data, goes in ~/Library/Application Support.

Documents and user data that is primary to the purpose of your app goes in ~/Documents, generally.

Preferences go in ~/Library/Preferences, but are generally read/written entirely via the `NSUserDefaults` API.

Answer (score 2):

~/Library/Application Support/YourAppName/yourFilesHere

This way the files will be personal to the user using your app. If you want tho files to be global they should be in your app bundle/Resources/

To get the home directory ( the tilde ~ ) you can use NSHomeDirectory or you could use [@"~" stringByExpandingTildeIntoPath];

Comment: @bbum Read my post, its there

Comment: I know -- along with a suggestion to do something completely wrong. ;)  The emphasis was more *don't do that*.

Answer (score -1):

You can store your application-created / application-deependant files in ~/Library/Application Support/YourApp/Files. Otherwise, user created Documents would most likely be best stored in the **Documents** directory.

Comment: This is not recommended practice (~/Library/YourApp).  There are more appropriate patterns to use, depending on role of the file/data.