# Working Directory in Objective-C and Xcode: debug mode vs. executable

Tags: objective-c, xcode, working-directory

I am writing a program in Objective-C using Xcode. My program creates a file as follows:

```
[@"" writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

I would like the file to be created in the same directory as the executable. When I run the program from Xcode, the file is created in the debug directory as expected.

However, when I run the .app file, the file is created in the root directory. How can I get the program to create a file in the directory where the .app file is located.

Thanks a lot.

EDIT: This is a MacOS application

EDIT2: Well, it seems that I shouldn't be writing to the .app directory. Thanks bbum and Paul R. What is the proper way to do it? To be more concrete, here's what I am doing: each time the user clicks a button in the application, a piece of hardware connected to a serial port will send a bunch data which will be written to a new file. This can happen any number of times while the application is running, so numerous files may be created. I would like them all created in the same folder.

Comment: With the edits, this is effectively a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007073/noob-where-can-i-store-my-applications-files/5007143#5007143

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must **never** make any assumptions about the initial working directory for your application, as this will depend on what method was used to launch it (e.g. Finder, Terminal (via `open`), Xcode, gdb, third party utility, etc). You should use an appropriate API to find a suitable directory to store temporary files or user-specific files or whatever it is you need to do. This should never be within the app's bundle and never at a path that is relative to the initial working directory.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any suggestions for APIs or what I should search for?

Comment: @user620139: Depends on what the files are for, but `NSSearchPathDirectory` should be a help: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSSearchPathDirectory

Answer (score 1):

You do *not* want the file to be created inside the `.app` wrapper.  That is *never* the right answer;   your application may easily be installed somewhere where the current user does not have write access to the `YourApp.app` wrapper.

(For example, my main user account is non-admin and all applications are installed admin-write-only.  If an app ever fails to work because it can't write to its app wrapper, the app goes in the trash.)

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007073/noob-where-can-i-store-my-applications-files/5007143#5007143) for an outline of where files should be stored.   Depends on the role of the file.

Comment: What do you mean by the .app wrapper?

Comment: I'm guessing he means the application *bundle*

Comment: Exactly; if your app is called `Foo` and builds into `Foo.app`, then that directory is the "app wrapper" and you **should never write anything into it once the app is installed on a user system**.